# Can Nginx limit incoming websocket message size?

Tags: nginx, websocket

In the [JS WebSocket library](https://github.com/websockets/ws), you can limit the maximum allowed incoming message size via the `maxPayload` [option](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/da42ea17451f11eed54adb54d3beeedbb1c2aa70/doc/ws.md#new-websocketserveroptions-callback).

I'd like to impose this limit in my Nginx reverse proxy layer, before it gets to my application server.

Does Nginx have a similar concept? Does `client_max_body_size` ([doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size)) apply to incoming websocket messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When nginx sees the 101 Switching Protocols response from the backend, it begins to [treat the connection as an opaque tunnel](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) and passes traffic back and forth without any further inspection. There is no directive that will limit any particular Websocket message in any way.

Comment: This is what I figured, thank you for confirming!