# How to limit the total volumn from a TCP connection

Tags: tcp, websocket, maximum, connlimit

I have a particular application with one type of connection that mostly sends packets to clients while receives nothing but login request. (i.e. video streaming)

Therefore I want to limit the Total Volumn Received from a TCP connection (websocket connection to be specific) within a maximum amount. Anything beyond that would result in connection drop.

At the application level, there is still not a limit on how large the websocket message received can be. So it is prone to sheer volumn attack until a security measure is enforced.

Thanks for any advice.
-- Add: CentOS Linux with Nginx or HAproxy as reverse proxy--

Comment: On which OS or which WS server ?

Comment: @Dom CentOS Linux with Nginx or HAproxy as reverse proxy

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1034906/can-nginx-limit-incoming-websocket-message-size